# How to make a microsecond-precise timer on the STM32L-Discovery ARM board?

Tags: timer, stm32, 1wire

I'm trying to implement the Dallas OneWire protocol, but I'm having trouble generating a microsecond delay on the STM32l-Discovery.

How do I implement a timer accurate enough to delay the program for x microseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For start I must tell you that there is no way to accomplish a precise usec delay using software. Even if you use an interrupt based system you will have latencies. Off course you can achieve a better accuracy with a larger CPU frequencies.

In order to connect with a 1-Wire device you can use:

- A external interface like [DS2482-100](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/DS2482-100.html)
- A software 1-wire implementation using pin polling.

For the second solution you have to call a software based delay. You can make a flag polling delay or an interrupt based flag polling delay. In both cases you **will be sure that a certain amount of time has passed but you can not be sure how match more time has passed**. This is because of the CPU latency, the CPU clock etc...

For example consider the following implementation. We program a HW TIMER to continuously count up and we check TIMER's value. We name "jiffy" the time between each TIMER's ticks and jiffies the TIMERS max value:

**Low level driver part (ex: driver.h)**

```
// ...
#define  JF_TIM_VALUE         (TIM7->CNT)
int JF_setfreq (uint32_t jf_freq, uint32_t jiffies);
// ...
```

**Low level driver part (ex: driver.c)**

```
// ...
#include <stm32l1xx.h>
#include <misc.h>
#include <stm32l1xx_rcc.h>
#include <stm32l1xx_tim.h>
/*
 * Time base configuration using the TIM7
 * \param jf_freq  The TIMER's frequency
 * \param jiffies  The TIMER's max count value
 */
int JF_setfreq (uint32_t jf_freq, uint32_t jiffies) {
   uint32_t psc=0;

   RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM7, ENABLE);
   SystemCoreClockUpdate ();

   if (jf_freq)
      psc = (SystemCoreClock / jf_freq) - 1;

   if (psc < 0xFFFF)       TIM7->PSC = psc;
   else                    return 1;

   if (jiffies < 0xFFFF)   TIM7->ARR = jiffies;
   else                    return 1;
   TIM7->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
   return 0;
}
// ...
```

**Middleware jiffy system with some delay implementations**
**jiffy.h:**

```
#include "string.h"

typedef int32_t   jiffy_t;    // Jiffy type 4 byte integer
typedef int (*jf_setfreq_pt) (uint32_t, uint32_t);   //Pointer to setfreq function

typedef volatile struct {
   jf_setfreq_pt  setfreq;       // Pointer to driver's timer set freq function
   jiffy_t        *value;        // Pointer to timers current value
   uint32_t       freq;          // timer's  frequency
   uint32_t       jiffies;       // jiffies max value (timer's max value)
   jiffy_t        jpus;          // Variable for the delay function
}jf_t;


/*
 *  ============= PUBLIC jiffy API =============
 */

/*
 * Link functions
 */
void jf_link_setfreq (jf_setfreq_pt pfun);
void jf_link_value (jiffy_t* v);

/*
 * User Functions
 */
void jf_deinit (void);
int jf_init (uint32_t jf_freq, uint32_t jiffies);

jiffy_t jf_per_usec (void);
void jf_delay_us (int32_t usec);
int jf_check_usec (int32_t usec);
```

**jiffy.c:**

```
#include "jiffy.h"

static jf_t _jf;
#define JF_MAX_TIM_VALUE      (0xFFFF)    // 16bit counters

//Connect the Driver's Set frequency function 
void jf_link_setfreq (jf_setfreq_pt pfun) {
   _jf.setfreq = pfun;
}

// Connect the timer's value to jiffy struct
void jf_link_value (jiffy_t* v) {
   _jf.value = v;
}

// De-Initialize the jf data and un-connect the functions
// from the driver
void jf_deinit (void) {
   memset ((void*)&_jf, 0, sizeof (jf_t));
}

// Initialise the jf to a desired jiffy frequency f
int jf_init (uint32_t jf_freq, uint32_t jiffies) {
   if (_jf.setfreq) {
      if ( _jf.setfreq (jf_freq, jiffies) )
         return 1;
      _jf.jiffies = jiffies;
      _jf.freq = jf_freq;
      _jf.jpus = jf_per_usec ();
      return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}

// Return the systems best approximation for jiffies per usec
jiffy_t jf_per_usec (void) {
   jiffy_t jf = _jf.freq / 1000000;

   if (jf <= _jf.jiffies)
      return jf;
   else
      // We can not count beyond timer's reload
      return 0;
}

/*!
 * \brief
 *    A code based delay implementation, using jiffies for timing.
 *    This is NOT accurate but it ensures that the time passed is always
 *    more than the requested value.
 *    The delay values are multiplications of 1 usec.
 * \param
 *    usec     Time in usec for delay
 */
void jf_delay_us (int32_t usec) {
   jiffy_t m, m2, m1 = *_jf.value;

   usec *= _jf.jpus;
   if (*_jf.value - m1 > usec) // Very small delays will return here.
      return;

   // Delay loop: Eat the time difference from usec value.
   while (usec>0) {
      m2 = *_jf.value;
      m = m2 - m1;
      usec -= (m>0) ? m : _jf.jiffies + m;
      m1 = m2;
   }
}

/*!
 * \brief
 *    A code based polling version delay implementation, using jiffies for timing.
 *    This is NOT accurate but it ensures that the time passed is always
 *    more than the requested value.
 *    The delay values are multiplications of 1 usec.
 * \param
 *    usec     Time in usec for delay
 */
 int jf_check_usec (int32_t usec) {
   static jiffy_t m1=-1, cnt;
   jiffy_t m, m2;

   if (m1 == -1) {
      m1 = *_jf.value;
      cnt = _jf.jpus * usec;
   }

   if (cnt>0) {
      m2 = *_jf.value;
      m = m2-m1;
      cnt-= (m>0) ? m : _jf.jiffies + m;
      m1 = m2;
      return 1;   // wait
   }
   else {
      m1 = -1;
      return 0;   // do not wait any more
   }
}
```

Hmmm you made it till here. Nice

So now you can use it in your application like this:
**main.c:**

```
#include "driver.h"
#include "jiffy.h"

void do_some_job1 (void) {
   // job 1
}
void do_some_job2 (void) {
   // job 2
}
int main (void) {
   jf_link_setfreq ((jf_setfreq_pt)JF_setfreq);  // link with driver
   jf_link_value ((jiffy_t*)&JF_TIM_VALUE);
   jf_init (1000000, 1000);  // 1MHz timer, 1000 counts, 1 usec per count

   // use delay version
   do_some_job1 ();
   jf_delay_us (300);  // wait for at least 300 usec
   do_some_job1 ();

   // use polling version
   do_some_job1 ();
   while (jf_check_usec (300)) {
      do_some_job2 ();  // keep calling for at least 300 usec
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this amazing and expansive answer.